# SwiftUI: List error Cannot call value of non-function type 'Binding<Subject>'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, xcode12

I'm trying to add 'onMove' and 'onDelete' actions in the list but I'm getting this errors:

[image]

Here is my implementation:

```
 @ObservedObject var itemsStore = TaskStore()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack{
                List{
                    ForEach(self.itemsStore.task) { task in
                        Text(task.todoItem)
                    }
                }.onMove{ self.$itemsStore.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1)}
                .onDelete{ self.$itemsStore.remove(atOffsets: $0) }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any of you knows why or how can fix this error to be able to use `onMove` and `onDelete` functions ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1st problem

You need to attach `.onMove` and `.onDelete` to the `ForEach`, rather than the `List`.

Here is your current code:

```
ZStack {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(self.itemsStore.task) { task in
                Text(task.todoItem)
            }
        }
        .onMove { self.$itemsStore.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1) }
        .onDelete { self.$itemsStore.remove(atOffsets: $0) }
    }
}
```

Which can be fixed like this (still has issues mentioned in 2nd part of answer):

```
ZStack {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(self.itemsStore.task) { task in
                Text(task.todoItem)
            }
            .onMove { self.$itemsStore.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1) }
            .onDelete { self.$itemsStore.remove(atOffsets: $0) }
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2nd problem

When you call [`move(fromOffsets:toOffset:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mutablecollection/3348325-move) you must call it on a `MutableCollection`, e.g. an Array. You are calling it on the binding of an object.

Perhaps you meant instead of:

```
self.$itemsStore.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1)
```

Something like:

```
self.itemsStore.task.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1)
```

Comment: Even when I made the changes you suggested I still get this error `Cannot call value of non-function type 'Binding<Subject>'` I think is because I'm using '@ObservedObject var itemsStore = TaskStore()'

Comment: @user2924482 Did you see the second part of the answer? I think that would solve it. This isn't a single issue you have here

Comment: `@ObservedObject var itemsStore = TaskStore()` how can be converted in a `MutableCollection ` ?

Comment: @user2924482 `TaskStore` is an object. You should use an array, like my suggestion. In the `ForEach` it look like you are using an array.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly imaging your `TaskStore` here is fixed part of code

```
List {
    ForEach(self.itemsStore.task) { task in
        Text(task.todoItem)
    }
    .onMove(perform: self.itemsStore.move)
    .onDelete(perform: self.itemsStore.remove)
}
```

the `.onMove` and `.onDelete` are modifiers of `ForEach` dynamic container so should be applied there, and put corresponding functions jut by reference.